# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.21.0:test without using maven-surfire-plugin and tests

Tags: java, maven

I am making a maven spring boot web application and am encountering errors which my team members are not. I was able to solve the error by adding the `javax.xml.bind` dependency, but my team members are able to run the application without this dependency, so I want to use the same version as them. I am posting the full maven-install stack-trace and (default) tests.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class HolidayApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

Error logs :

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:139)
>   [spring-boot-test-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
>   [spring-test-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
>   [spring-test-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
>   [spring-test-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
>   [spring-test-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
>   [spring-test-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
>   [spring-test-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227) [spring-test-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
>   [spring-test-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>         at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
>   [spring-test-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
>   [spring-test-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
>   [spring-test-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>         at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>   [spring-test-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
>   [spring-test-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>         at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
>   [spring-test-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:365)
>   [surefire-junit4-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
>         at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:273)
>   [surefire-junit4-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
>         at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238)
>   [surefire-junit4-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
>         at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:159)
>   [surefire-junit4-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
>         at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:379)
>   [surefire-booter-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
>         at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:340)
>   [surefire-booter-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
>         at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:125)
>   [surefire-booter-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
>         at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:413)
>   [surefire-booter-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
>       Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
>         at org.hibernate.boot.spi.XmlMappingBinderAccess.(XmlMappingBinderAccess.java:43)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.(MetadataSources.java:87)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:209)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:164)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
>         at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:51)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         ... 42 common frames omitted
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
>         at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
>   ~[na:na]
>         at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
>   ~[na:na]
>         at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
>   ~[na:na]
>         ... 53 common frames omitted
>       2018-08-16 10:33:11.742 ERROR 9172 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while
>   allowing TestExecutionListener
>   [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@1921ad94]
>   to prepare test instance
>   [com.enjoying.holidayApplication.HolidayApplication.HolidayApplicationTests@2ca3d826]
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
>         at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
>   ~[spring-test-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
>   ~[spring-test-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
>   ~[spring-test-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
>   ~[spring-test-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
>   ~[spring-test-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227) [spring-test-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
>   [spring-test-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>         at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
>   [spring-test-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
>   [spring-test-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
>   [spring-test-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>         at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>   [spring-test-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
>   [spring-test-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>         at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
>   [spring-test-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:365)
>   [surefire-junit4-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
>         at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:273)
>   [surefire-junit4-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
>         at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238)
>   [surefire-junit4-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
>         at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:159)
>   [surefire-junit4-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
>         at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:379)
>   [surefire-booter-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
>         at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:340)
>   [surefire-booter-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
>         at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:125)
>   [surefire-booter-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
>         at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:413)
>   [surefire-booter-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
>       Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:139)
>   ~[spring-boot-test-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
>   ~[spring-test-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
>   ~[spring-test-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         ... 27 common frames omitted
>       Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
>         at org.hibernate.boot.spi.XmlMappingBinderAccess.(XmlMappingBinderAccess.java:43)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.(MetadataSources.java:87)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:209)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:164)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
>         at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:51)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>         ... 42 common frames omitted
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
>         at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
>   ~[na:na]
>         at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
>   ~[na:na]
>         at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
>   ~[na:na]
>         ... 53 common frames omitted
>       [ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 4.915 s <<< FAILURE! - in
>   com.enjoying.holidayApplication.HolidayApplication.HolidayApplicationTests
>       [ERROR] contextLoads(com.enjoying.holidayApplication.HolidayApplication.HolidayApplicationTests)
>   Time elapsed: 0.006 s  <<< ERROR!
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
>       Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
>       Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
>
> [INFO] 
>   [INFO] Results:
>   [INFO] 
>   [ERROR] Errors: 
>   [ERROR]   HolidayApplicationTests.contextLoads » IllegalState Failed to load Application...
>   [INFO] 
>   [ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
>   [INFO] 
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO] Total time: 8.069 s
>   [INFO] Finished at: 2018-08-16T10:33:12+02:00
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.21.0:test
>   (default-test) on project HolidayApplication: There are test failures.
>       [ERROR] 
>       [ERROR] Please refer to C:\git-project\evidencija-godisnjih-odmora\HolidayApplication\target\surefire-reports
>   for the individual test results.
>       [ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and
>   [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
>       [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
>       [ERROR] 
>       [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
>       [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>       [ERROR] 
>       [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>       [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

Comment: Which Spring Boot version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by switching from java 10 to java 8.

Comment: It's just because this class is not currently in default class path and what's more It will be completely removed in Java 11.